# What do you say during the final Tashahhud, and when standing up from Rukuu'?

Tags: salat, dua, tashahhud

What is obligatory to say in salah?

**Question:** In salah, is saying: *rabbi ighfir li* (Arabic: ربى اغفر لى) and *rabbana wa lak al-hamd* (Arabic: ربنا ولك الحمد) obligatory or is it sunnah?

Also when you do the final Tashahhud in Dhuhr, Asr, and Maghrib prayers, do you start with "Attahi-atu-lilla-hee" or do you start with lifting your finger and saying "Ash-hadu-ala-ila-ha-illalah"

**Question:** How should I start the final Tashahhud?

Comment: You should probably find a local teacher.